# Is it possible to access to NFC functionalities from a React App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've to build an app for Android using React Native and I would love to understand if I can access the NFC functionalities. I could see something related to Cordova, but as far as I'm new to native mobile web app I wanted to search further.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"native mobile web app"* doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You can bridge the worlds of React/JS and Native Modules; check out [the documentation on Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content).

Comment: m0skit0 - a 'native mobile app' that redirects to a responsive website, would be my best guess :)

Answer (score 3):

We have recently released on GitHub [react-native-nfc](https://github.com/Novadart/react-native-nfc).
The goal of the project is to support NFC operations in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by writing a Java module, which [encapsulates the NFC functionality](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html). This module can be later [bridged with react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content) and used in your javascript code.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is a project that try to make that [bridge](https://github.com/Lube/nfc-react-native)

I still try to use it, but it work :-)